# Handling orientation changes with dynamic spinners

Tags: android, spinner, httprequest, android-configchanges

I have searched the web and keep trying for 5 hours but I couldn't find a way to solve the problem. I want to keep the state of my spinners after orientation changes.

I have 2 spinners which are created dynamically. They get their items by http request and the first spinner changes the items in the second one by setOnItemSelectedListener() method. I read the Strings into Global Lists.

```
public class Global {
    public static String userName;
    public static String userType;
    public static String serverIp;
    public static int spinnerLeaguePos=0;
    public static int spinnerMatchPos=0;
    public static List<String> leagues;
    public static List<String> matches;
}
```

My first problem was preventing the activity from restart.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

I have made this change in my manifest file to handle orientation changes by myself and avoid activity from restart.

I have found a way for handling orientation changes on internet but it doesn't worked for me. I'm getting null pointer exception when I change the orientation.

```
07-05 12:41:08.119: E/AndroidRuntime(26388): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-05 12:41:08.119: E/AndroidRuntime(26388): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.MatchSelectionActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-05 12:41:08.119: E/AndroidRuntime(26388):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
07-05 12:41:08.119: E/AndroidRuntime(26388):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
07-05 12:41:08.119: E/AndroidRuntime(26388):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3351)
07-05 12:41:08.119: E/AndroidRuntime(26388):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-05 12:41:08.119: E/AndroidRuntime(26388):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1151)
07-05 12:41:08.119: E/AndroidRuntime(26388):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-05 12:41:08.119: E/AndroidRuntime(26388):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-05 12:41:08.119: E/AndroidRuntime(26388):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-05 12:41:08.119: E/AndroidRuntime(26388):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 12:41:08.119: E/AndroidRuntime(26388):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-05 12:41:08.119: E/AndroidRuntime(26388):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-05 12:41:08.119: E/AndroidRuntime(26388):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-05 12:41:08.119: E/AndroidRuntime(26388):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-05 12:41:08.119: E/AndroidRuntime(26388): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-05 12:41:08.119: E/AndroidRuntime(26388):    at com.example.MatchSelectionActivity.setLeagues(MatchSelectionActivity.java:90)
07-05 12:41:08.119: E/AndroidRuntime(26388):    at com.example.MatchSelectionActivity.onCreate(MatchSelectionActivity.java:47)
07-05 12:41:08.119: E/AndroidRuntime(26388):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-05 12:41:08.119: E/AndroidRuntime(26388):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-05 12:41:08.119: E/AndroidRuntime(26388):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
07-05 12:41:08.119: E/AndroidRuntime(26388):    ... 12 more
```

This is what I have done so far. I don't even sure about to way I'm trying to do it. So any more appropriate way for doing this will be appreciated.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    spinnerLeague = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_league);
    spinnerMatch = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_match);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        setLeagues();
        setMatches();
        spinnerLeague.setSelection(Global.spinnerLeaguePos);
        spinnerMatch.setSelection(Global.spinnerMatchPos);
    }
    else{
        Global.leagues = new ArrayList<String>();
        Global.matches = new ArrayList<String>();

        Global.leagues.add(getString(R.string.league_select));
        Global.matches.add(getString(R.string.match_select));

        GetLeagues task = new GetLeagues();
        String requestString = "http://" + Global.serverIp + ":8080/server/GetCurrentLeagues";
        task.execute(new String[] { requestString });
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.match_selection_layout);

}

public class GetLeagues extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {
    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... urls) {
        //this part works properly, and reads the leagues into Global.leagues List
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        setLeagues();
    }
}
public class GetMatches extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {
    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... urls) {
        //this part works properly, and reads the matches into Global.matches List
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        setMatches();
    }
}

 public void setLeagues() {

    spinnerLeague = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_league);
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Global.leagues);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerLeague.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    spinnerLeague.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            spinnerLeague = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_league);

            if(position!=0){
                spinnerMatch.setEnabled(true);
                Global.spinnerLeaguePos=position;

                GetMatches task = new GetMatches();
                String requestString = "http://" + Global.serverIp +":8080/server/GetCurrentMatches/"+Global.spinnerLeaguePos;
                task.execute(new String[] { requestString });
            }
            else{
                setMatches();
                spinnerMatch.setEnabled(false);
                Global.spinnerLeaguePos=position;
            }

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
  }

    public void setMatches() {

    spinnerMatch = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_match);
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Global.matches);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerMatch.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


    spinnerMatch.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Global.spinnerMatchPos=position;
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
  }
```

Comment: it would help if you printed the whole stack trace of the nullpointerexception.

Comment: perhaps you should take a look at the method onConfigChanged(). It lets you deal with configurations changes really easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `setContentView(R.layout.match_selection_layout)` before calling `findViewById`. Otherwise, `findViewById` will return `null` (since the parent `View` has not yet been inflated/attached to the screen).

Also you should ***not*** use `configChanges` as a bandaid to fix your activity. There are many ways an `Activity` can be restarted; for example, if the user changed the device's language setting from English to Spanish (this would cause the entire `Activity` to be destroyed and created). Always make sure orientation changes work correctly... don't just give up on them and simply override `onConfigurationChanged`.

Comment: setting content view seems to be working. But I think I should use "public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)" method. Is there any helpful tutorial for using it?

Comment: what is your reason for using `configChanges`? I'll try and find one but you should have a good reason for using it before you do...

Comment: I want to handle orientation changes only. I need to change screen display depending on orientation. If you are asking why don't I forbid orientation changes , I think it would be better for users to use the app the way they want to.

Comment: @Srht you will never, ever, ***ever*** tell *anyone*, *ever*, no matter how long I live, (*ever*, **ever**, ***ever***) to forbid screen orientation changes. I hate that more than anything... it's just lazy on the developer's part lol

Comment: What you could do instead is create two separate layouts with the same name (one for landscape mode and one for portrait mode). Then put your portrait layout in `res/layout` (this is the default, fallback layout), and put the landscape layout in `res/layout-land`. This will ensure that the correct layout is chosen at runtime.

Comment: Handling the config change programatically is usually a lot more work than you need to do. Using static xml layouts/folders makes things a whole lot easier.

Comment: So, I don't want to be lazy and handle orientation changes. I have searched a lot for a useful tutorial but end up with nothing. I need a simple understanding about the onConfigurationChanged method. Does it make changes on running activity or does it give programmer a chance to save his data before activity getting restarted?

Comment: Does it make any changes to what?

Comment: Maybe you should explain what exactly it is you are trying to do.

Comment: I can't move to the chat because of my reputation and don't want to mess up here with comments. Maybe we may communicate via e-mail or something (if you don't mind.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13469/discussion-between-alex-lockwood-and-srht)